# Twitter Bootstrap Tab Selection Not Changing Content

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Although there are plenty of Twitter Bootstrap questions open that regard similar issues to that which I'm having, I haven't been able to find any solutions to my particular issue.  I'm using the twitter bootstraps "tab" feature in order to display content, and while the script succeeds in changing the changing the active tab, the content remains the same.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, Tabs!</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


     <h3>Version Information:</h3>
     <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
             <li class="active">
                 <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__0" data-toggle="tab">9424</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__1" data-toggle="tab">9058</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__2" data-toggle="tab">8928</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__3" data-toggle="tab">8926</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__4" data-toggle="tab">8924</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__5" data-toggle="tab">8890</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__6" data-toggle="tab">8889</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__7" data-toggle="tab">8887</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
         <div class="tab-content">
             <div class="tab-pane active" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__0">
                 <p>
                 Author: joe<br>
                 Version: v9424 (1:31 pm February 28, 2013)<br>
                 Action: Modified<br>
                 Message: Finalized a bit of the code... should be better now.<br>
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__1">
                 <p>
                 Author: joe<br>
                 Version: v9058 (9:13 pm February 26, 2013)<br>
                 Action: Modified<br>
                 Message: Hello, world!<br>
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__2">
                 <p>
                 Author: joe<br>
                 Version: v8928 (2:08 am February 25, 2013)<br>
                 Action: Modified<br>
                 Message: Hello, world!<br>
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__3">
                 <p>
                 Author: joe<br>
                 Version: v8926 (1:14 am February 25, 2013)<br>
                 Action: Modified<br>
                 Message: Hello, world!<br>
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__4">
                 <p>
                 Author: joe<br>
                 Version: v8924 (10:26 pm February 24, 2013)<br>
                 Action: Modified<br>
                 Message: Hello, world!<br>
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__5">
                 <p>
                 Author: joe<br>
                 Version: v8890 (9:59 pm February 23, 2013)<br>
                 Action: Modified<br>
                 Message: Hello, world!<br>
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__6">
                 <p>
                 Author: joe<br>
                 Version: v8889 (9:53 pm February 23, 2013)<br>
                 Action: Added<br>
                 Message: Hello, world!<br>
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__7">
                 <p>
                 Author: joe<br>
                 Version: v8887 (9:40 pm February 23, 2013)<br>
                 Action: Added<br>
                 Message: Hello, world!<br>
                 </p>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.nav-tabs').tab();
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

All the dependence files are loaded just fine when I run this (for reference, the version of bootstrap being used is 2.3.1).  I've been head-desking about this problem for quite some time now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/C3gQb/2/) a jsfiddle link containing the error code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to move the Bootstrap script reference **above** your ready event. So, the bottom of your page should look like this:

```
<script src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.nav-tabs').tab();
});
</script>
```

Also, since you specified an HTML5 doctype, the `type` attribute is optional in the `script` tag.

**EDIT 2**:

I'm fairly certain you can get rid of the manual tab binding - I don't use it on my site, and this jsFiddle doesn't do it either: http://jsfiddle.net/C3gQb/

As you can see, you just need to bind the click events of your "tabs", and then it will work. This should work:

```
<script src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ 
    $('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });  
});
</script>
```

If it doesn't, I suspect there is something unusual about your browser/dev environment that isn't obvious from what you've posted.

**EDIT 4**

Yeah, we've isolated the problem with your new jsFiddle. I tweaked the top 2 for this version: http://jsfiddle.net/C3gQb/4/ - and those two now work:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h3>Version Information:</h3>
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#project-src-Graph-Graph-pm__0" data-toggle="tab">9424</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#project-src-Graph-Graph-pm__1" data-toggle="tab">9058</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__2" data-toggle="tab">8928</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__3" data-toggle="tab">8926</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__4" data-toggle="tab">8924</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__5" data-toggle="tab">8890</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__6" data-toggle="tab">8889</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__7" data-toggle="tab">8887</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="project-src-Graph-Graph-pm__0">
      <p>
        Author: joe<br>
        Version: v9424 (1:31 pm February 28, 2013)<br>
        Action: Modified<br>
        Message: Finalized a bit of the code... should be better now.<br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="project-src-Graph-Graph-pm__1">
      <p>
        Author: joe<br>
        Version: v9058 (9:13 pm February 26, 2013)<br>
        Action: Modified<br>
        Message: Hello, world!<br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__2">
      <p>
        Author: joe<br>
        Version: v8928 (2:08 am February 25, 2013)<br>
        Action: Modified<br>
        Message: Hello, world!<br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__3">
      <p>
        Author: joe<br>
        Version: v8926 (1:14 am February 25, 2013)<br>
        Action: Modified<br>
        Message: Hello, world!<br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__4">
      <p>
        Author: joe<br>
        Version: v8924 (10:26 pm February 24, 2013)<br>
        Action: Modified<br>
        Message: Hello, world!<br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__5">
      <p>
        Author: joe<br>
        Version: v8890 (9:59 pm February 23, 2013)<br>
        Action: Modified<br>
        Message: Hello, world!<br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__6">
      <p>
        Author: joe<br>
        Version: v8889 (9:53 pm February 23, 2013)<br>
        Action: Added<br>
        Message: Hello, world!<br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="project/src/Graph/Graph.pm__7">
      <p>
        Author: joe<br>
        Version: v8887 (9:40 pm February 23, 2013)<br>
        Action: Added<br>
        Message: Hello, world!<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried putting the script reference in a number of places, but to no avail.  The same behavior results if I place the include in the location that you've listed.

Comment: @AverageJoe The script reference for sure needs to be above the ready event. Do you have Firebug installed?

Comment: Yes, I've been using Firebug to isolate the issue.  From what I can see, the primary issue is that the updates are only happening on click to the tabs and not the content panes.

Comment: Also, I tried changing the script code to what you've described and I encounter the same problem.

Comment: I replaced the code in the jsfiddle with something a bit more representative of my actual code.  I've placed the link in the updated opening post.

Comment: @AverageJoe Yeah, and that shows the problem right away: your ID values are **not** valid.

Comment: And here I've been ripping my hair out trying to resolve any weird bootstrap dependencies that I didn't account for!  I wasn't aware that the slash was an invalid identification character in HTML.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25738/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-average-joe)

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are referencing an older version of jQuery. Can you upgrade it to `1.9.x`? I don't think they are working with an older version of jQuery.

Also, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-tabs').tab();
});
</script>
```

And also, please move the `bootstrap.min.js` before the function.

Comment: I downloaded jquery v1.9.1, included it on the page, and hoisted the inclusion of 'bootstrap.min.js', but now the tab switching behavior won't even function (i.e. now neither the tabs themselves nor the content is updated).  Perhaps I'm going about including JQuery incorrectly?  If I shouldn't load it locally, what URL can I grab it from?

Note: I was careful about placing the JQuery inclusion above the bootstrap inclusion (placing JQuery above bootstrap), so I don't think that could be the issue.

Comment: Great that you have solved. What was the issue? Say in a line?

Comment: The issue wasn't with bootstrap, but rather with the identifiers I was using for HTML tags (I was using slashes in IDs when those aren't allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Just check the bootstrap version... it should be v2.3.1 +