# How to show tab contents with Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a view in my MVC application which has the below tab.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="pnav-tabs">
     <li class="active" id="requiredtab-li"><a href="#requiredtab" id="requiredtab-id" data-toggle="tab"><span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>Step 1:</strong></span> Enter required fields</a></li>
     <li id="optionaltab-li"><a href="#optionaltab" id="optionaltab-id" data-toggle="tab"><span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>Step 2:</strong></span> Enter optional fields</a></li>
     <li id="uploadtab-li"  ><a href="#uplaodtab" id="uploadtab-id" data-toggle="tab"><span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>Step 3:</strong></span>Upload your video</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

      <div class="tab-pane active" id="requiredtab">

         TAB CONTENT

       </div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="optionaltab">   

    TAB CONTENT

</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="uplaodtab">       

   TAB CONTENT
</div>
```

When my page loads I disable the “Optional” and “Upload” tabs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#uploadtab-li').attr('class', 'disabled');
    $('#optionaltab-li').attr('class', 'disabled');
    $('#uploadtab-id').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    $('#optionaltab-id').removeAttr('data-toggle');
});
```

When the required fields are filled on the "RequiredTab" I click on the below next button which calls the RequiredNext() function and should make the optional tab active and show the optional fields.

Here is the function:

```
function RequiredNext(e) {
    var isRequiredFilled = ValidateInputs();
    if (isRequiredFilled == true) {
        $('#optionaltab-id').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
        $('#optionaltab-li').attr('class', 'active');
        //$('#requiredtab-li').attr('class', 'disabled');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.pnav-tabs a[href=#optionaltab]').tab('show');
    } else {
        alert("The optional fields cannot be accessed until the required fields are filled");
    }
}
```

The above function makes the optional tab active but I cannot see the fields on the tab. The fields of the required tab are still showing at the point

Also the first tab "Required tab appears to be still active.

I have followed the example here which didn’t work:

[Twitter Bootstrap Tab Selection Not Changing Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262440/twitter-bootstrap-tab-selection-not-changing-content)

How can I show the content on the Optional tab after clicking on the next button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace in your code: `$('#optionaltab-id').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
        $('#optionaltab-li').attr('class', 'active');
        //$('#requiredtab-li').attr('class', 'disabled');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.pnav-tabs a[href=#optionaltab]').tab('show');` with:

```
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#optionaltab-li').removeClass('disabled');
    $('#requiredtab-li').addClass('disabled');
    $('#pnav-tabs li a[href=#optionaltab]').tab('show');
```

The tab will handle your class changes. You use `.pnav-tabs` which refer to a class while you use an id so use `#pnav-tabs` instead.